# GCC attribute no_instrument_function not working

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, instrumentation, gnu-coreutils

I am trying to add entey/exit hooks to `ls` in the `coreutils` package. I followed instuctions from here to get the source and build it:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/976002/how-to-compile-the-sorcecode-of-the-offical-ls-c-source-code

Now, to add hooks, i modiified `ls` code as:

Makefile

```
diff --git a/src/local.mk b/src/local.mk

+src_ls_CFLAGS = -g  -finstrument-functions
+src_ls_LDFLAGS = -ldl -rdynamic
```

and the hooks  in ls source:

```
diff --git a/src/ls.c b/src/ls.c

+void __attribute__((no_instrument_function))
+__cyg_profile_func_enter (void *this_fn,
+                               void *call_site)
+{
+    printf("hacked [+]\n");
+}
+
+void __attribute__((no_instrument_function))
+__cyg_profile_func_exit  (void *this_fn,
+                               void *call_site)
+{
+    printf("hacked [-]\n");
+}
```

But now when I run `ls`, it crashes:

```
// looks like stack depth exceeded but reports segmentation fault:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004057de in printf (__fmt=<synthetic pointer>) at src/ls.c:263
263     {
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004057de in printf (__fmt=<synthetic pointer>) at src/ls.c:263
#1  __cyg_profile_func_enter (this_fn=<optimized out>, call_site=<optimized out>) at src/ls.c:266
#2  0x00000000004057e3 in printf (__fmt=<synthetic pointer>) at src/ls.c:263
#3  __cyg_profile_func_enter (this_fn=<optimized out>, call_site=<optimized out>) at src/ls.c:266
#4  0x00000000004057e3 in printf (__fmt=<synthetic pointer>) at src/ls.c:263
#5  __cyg_profile_func_enter (this_fn=<optimized out>, call_site=<optimized out>) at src/ls.c:266
#6  0x00000000004057e3 in printf (__fmt=<synthetic pointer>) at src/ls.c:263
. . . . 
#712011 __cyg_profile_func_enter (this_fn=<optimized out>, call_site=<optimized out>) at src/ls.c:266
< still running >
```

Why `__attribute__((no_instrument_function))` in entry/exit hook functions not working??

```
(gdb) disas __cyg_profile_func_enter
Dump of assembler code for function __cyg_profile_func_enter:
   0x00000000004057d0 <+0>:     sub    $0x8,%rsp
   0x00000000004057d4 <+4>:     mov    $0x404aa0,%edi
   0x00000000004057d9 <+9>:     mov    0x8(%rsp),%rsi
=> 0x00000000004057de <+14>:    callq  0x4057d0 <__cyg_profile_func_enter>
   0x00000000004057e3 <+19>:    mov    $0x41b3cf,%edi
   0x00000000004057e8 <+24>:    callq  0x404920 <puts@plt>
   0x00000000004057ed <+29>:    mov    0x8(%rsp),%rsi
   0x00000000004057f2 <+34>:    mov    $0x404aa0,%edi
   0x00000000004057f7 <+39>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
   0x00000000004057fb <+43>:    jmp    0x4057a0 <__cyg_profile_func_exit>
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

Coreutils source: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/